# Initial API token before user authentication - .NET core Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, jwt

I have a web application in which i have to call a some APIs after and before user login. I would like to secure the calls before login as well. Like, SaveUserAPI, ForgotPasswordAPI while signing up.

I have used JWT token mechanism for generating token after use logged in, in the subsequent calls this token will be used for API authentication.

How should i make the SaveUserAPI, ForgotPasswordAPI calls which are called when user is not logged in? Can you provide some valuable suggestions to approach this?

Comment: Use HTTPS, AntiFrogeryToken.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadHannan. I was not looking for a solution for both Mobile and Web. All API calls should be authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using OAuth2, you can generate two kinds of authentication mechanisms for your APIs.

1. client-credentials flow: machine-to-machine auth using bearer tokens
2. implicit or authorization_code flow: this will be used APIs requiring user's identity

Then you can use Policy/Scope on your APIs to lock down the Register, Forgot Password kind of APIs to use client-credentials and the other apis can use the implicit/auth code flow.

I've done the same in my backend API which is being used by SPAs and mobile apps.

None of my apis allows anonymous access. This means the app needs to authorize and manage two tokens, one for non-user endpoints and the other token for user-linked apis.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for similar approach. None of the APIs should  be accessed anonymously. Hope the client credentials will be used for external calls and user based token for all the calls after the login.

In the request pipleline of the asp.net core, how did you configure?

Comment: I defined a required scope for the non-user apis and applied it via a policy on the pipeline